# Access VBA restore listbox selection after requery based on a non-bound column

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba

So, I inherited MS Access 2010 (and 2013 now) code that has a listbox bound to a column that is not unique.  However, that bound value is used in code, so, I cannot change which column is bound.  But, I have a subform that needs to requery the listbox on the parent form.  What I am struggling with is how to restore the selection in the parent's listbox to what item was selected before the listbox was requeried.

I have tried storing the Parent.List0 value before the requery and then using Parent.List0.Selected and Parent.List0.ItemData, but these do not seem to work because, presumably, the listbox is bound to a column that is not unique.

There *is* a column in the listbox that is unique.  The 4th column (column(3)) is unique, but I'm not finding a way to select a listbox item based on a column other than the bound column.

I am confident someone has some ideas that will sort this out, but I've not been able to locate any solutions in my search of the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am in version 2010 and while testing, I was unable to replicate a situation where the list box loses its value.  Neither on a bound form or an unbound form.

In any case however, it seems that column 3 has a unique key - so you can use that.

```
' Assuming this code runs from within the sub-form
KeyID = Me.Parent.Controls("MyListBox").Column(3)
With Me.Parent.Controls("MyListBox")
  .Requery ' Or do whatever you do that causes it to requery

  ' Find the previously selected item and select
  For i = 0 To (.ListCount - 1)
    If .Column(3, i) = KeyID Then
      .Selected(i) = True
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
End With
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Right:  It _does_ change, hence the question.

Comment: However, the change is only to one value in one field. I need that change to display, but the # of items in the list doesn't change and the order of items in the list doesn't change. But, I cannot get the .selected(prevListIndex) = True to actually select the correct item--no error, it just doesn't select any item in the listbox. I did think about the for..next loop, but seems like there must be a better way than looping through potentially 100-some items.  Guess I'll have to do that.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you very much, DHW.  That works great and is pretty speedy too.  I still cannot understand why one cannot just set a listbox to a specific row index in the list--seems like Access should store an index reference that is unrelated to the actual data stored in the list.  But, since it doesn't, your code solves it nicely.  Thank you!

Comment: For folks who find this thread later, I applied a minor tweak to DHW's code:  instead of .Column(2) and .Column(2, i), I changed it to .Column(3) and .Column(3, i) since Column 4 was the unique column and the .Column property is zero-based (unlike the bound column property which starts at 1, not 0).

Comment: I'll make the edit.  To answer your question about access retaining the list index - during a requery the contents of the listbox may change.  As I pointed out in my answer - I did a test database to ensure my solution was valid and I noticed that Access preserved the ListBox value.  There also may be a way of setting the Listbox Control directly using a windows API call - but that may be trying to kill a mosquito with a cannon.